# sql regexp filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in column 'sub' in mysql database :
1=0|2=0|3=0, 3=0, 1=0, 2=0

How to filter '2=0' from 'sub' with regexp mysql ?

i was try

```
SELECT * FROM `men` WHERE `sub` REGEXP '2{0,1)=0'
```

but the result is more than 1. I want only '2=0' for my result.

please, is that any solution for me ?

Comment: The question is not clear. Please give multiple examples.

Comment: Are you trying to remove duplicates? change `1=0|2=0|3=0, 3=0, 1=0, 2=0` to `1=0|2=0|3=0`?

Answer (score 0):

> I want only '2=0' for my result

Use the beginning of the string `^` and the end of the string `$` anchors.

`REGEXP`, in this case, would be good to find dynamic numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM men WHERE sub REGEXP '^[0-9]=0$'
```

for such simple case (*I want only '2=0' for my result*) it's achievable without *regexp* :

```
SELECT * FROM men WHERE sub = '2=0'
```

Comment: If you think that this is the request, than this would be the solution - `SELECT * FROM men WHERE sub = '2=0'`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, added as alternative

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LIKE` operator

For all rows containing `2=0`

```
SELECT * FROM men WHERE sub LIKE '%2=0%'
```

For containing just `2=0`

```
SELECT * FROM men WHERE sub = '2=0'
```

Comment: If you think that this is the request, than this would be the solution - `SELECT * FROM men WHERE sub = '2=0'`

Comment: I think that's the solution, i have to update the answer :)